# NodeJS Strange Req Parameters

Tags: node.js

I have multiple pages like index, categories, subcategories, category_product etc.

As shown below

```
const homeController = require('./controllers/homeController');
const categoryController = require('./controllers/categoryController');
const productController = require('./controllers/productController')

app.get('/', homeController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product/:product', productController.index);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory/:category_product', categoryController.products);
app.get('/:category/:subcategory', categoryController.subcategory);
app.get('/:category', categoryController.index);
```

I have category controller

## INDEX PAGE

```
exports.index = function(req, res){
  categoryModel.find(function(err, categories) {
    res.render('index', {data : 'hi' , categories : categories})
  });
};
```

Index works perfectly but when im in index.ejs, subcategory works i dont know why.

## SUB CATEGORY

```
exports.subcategory = function(req,res){
    var category = req.params.category
    var subcategory= req.params.subcategory

    console.log(category)
    console.log(subcategory)
    categoryModel.find(function(err, allCategories) {  //NOT TO LOSE MENS OR WOMENS FROM NAVBAR !
        categoryModel.find({'id':category},{'categories': {$elemMatch: {'id': subcategory}}},function (err, subcategory) {
            var title = subcategory[0].categories[0].page_title
            var subcategory = subcategory[0].categories[0]
            res.render('subcategory',{title:title, subcategory : subcategory, allCategories : allCategories})  //WOW
          });
    });
};
```

Console outputs are

```
js
angular.min.js.map
```

I really dont know what is going on? Why is this happening?

Application crashes at the beginning because of this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I changed

```
<script src="/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="/js/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Now everything works good.